# Browser tab freezes after using useState hook in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

This is a very simple client component:

```
'use client';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function MultiplePosts({posts, session, slug}) {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Count has been updated:', count);
    }, []);


    function incrementCount() {
        setCount(count + 1);
    }

    return (
        <div className={"post-infinite-container"}>
            <p>Count: {count}</p>
            <button onClick={() => incrementCount()}>Increment</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

From start I wanted to use it as infinite scroll, but face the problem. When I somehow interact with useState - it freezes the tab and I can't even close it. Even in this very simple example I face it.

I've read tons of other questions about my problem, but can't find a solution for it. It's kinda driving my crazy already.

What have I done alredy:

1. Checked if any components are causing multiple re-renders - no. Two is a maximum re-renders I have.
2. Off all components around the problem one. Did not help.

Please, maybe someone faced the problem before me.. I just don't understand why this is happening. It's too simple to cause THIS problems.

Comment: Check if you have some code that you're running outside of useEffect in one of your components. It could be getting executed a huge amount of times.

Comment: @Aymendps, Thank you for a reply! It is a kinda small app, so I can tell you with confidence that I am not using useEffect anywhere else. I have multiple functions in PostFooter component. These functions should be activated on button click event and process like action. Maybe, I should wrap them in useEffect? They are working correctly on detail post page and don't raise any freezrs, but.. idk

Comment: What you should check for is if you're calling a function using () operator or some other code outside of useEffect or events like button clicks and so on. You say you're not using useEffect in your other components. Perhaps you're calling an expensive function or setState function directly, because that will cause react to re-render infinitely.

Comment: Well, thank tou a lot! I call functions like that: onClick={() => handleLoadMore(post.id)}. I think it is a problem in this case. I'll check it rn!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: One client component was marked as async. It causes infinite re-renders. **Don't use async functions in client components.** Never

Answer (score 2):

Trenton McKinney's answer was exactly what was going wrong in my code. Don't use async functions in client components